# Picking elements in a list in Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, list

In Python 2.7.6, a list as below. In what way I can pick up the items begins with "4" and length of 4, i.e. 4646 and 4648 below?

```
aaa = [2013, 2014, 2002, 4646, 4648, 20, 456, 5623, 'abc']
```

I can only work out picking the length of 4 ones by:

```
results = []

for number in aaa:
  if len(str(number)) == 4:
      results.append(number)

print results
```

Thanks.

---

all are wonderful answers. but I am a newbie, so choose the easiest one. :)

Comment: Unless you might have strings starting with 4 too, why not filter on `range(4000, 5000)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wonder this is what you want

```
results = []

for number in aaa:
  if str(number)[0] == '4' and len(str(number)) == 4:
      results.append(number)

print results
```

Answer (score 5):

With integers:

```
result = [x for x in aaa if 4000 <= x < 5000]
```

With strings:

```
result = [x for x in aaa if len(str(x)) == 4 and str(x).startswith('4')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using filter:

```
filtered = list(filter(lambda x: len(str(x)) == 4 and str(x)[0] == '4', aaa))
```

Using list comprehension:

```
filtered = [ x for x in aaa if len(str(x)) == 4 and str(x)[0] == '4' ]
```

Using generator expression:

```
ge = ( x for x in aaa if len(str(x)) == 4 and str(x)[0] == '4' )
filtered = list(ge)
```

filtered is now: `[4646, 4648]`

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
aaa = [2013, 2014, 2002, 4646, 4648, 20, 456, 5623, 'abc']
result = [x for x in aaa if str(x).startswith("4") and len(str(x))==4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will fetch you the desired result.

```
aaa = [2013, 2014, 2002, 4646, 4648, 20, 456, 5623, 'abc']
results = []
for number in aaa:
    if len(str(number)) == 4 and str(number).split()[0][0] == '4':
        results.append(number)
print results 

Output: [4646, 4648]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these lines of code:

```
aaa = [2013, 2014, 2002, 4646, 4648, 20, 456, 5623, 'abc']

results = []

for number in aaa:
  if len(str(number)) == 4 and str(number)[0] == '4':
  results.append(number)

print results
```

I have changed, only, your if statement like :

> if len(str(number)) == 4 and str(number)[0] == '4':